# .NET framework version used

Tags: .net

I have a third-party program installed, and I want to find out what version of the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework it is using.

How do I figure that out?

Comment: Programatically? or is using a utility for it ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start up the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, go to the folder your assembly is in, type `corflags.exe assemblyName.dll`, and you should get the following information back.

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

Comment: What do I do on a client machine that does not have visual studio installed?

Comment: Raj, CorFlags.exe is part of the Windows SDK can be found here
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\corflags.exe, I am unsure what dependcies it has but you could try running it as individual .exe on the client machine

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do that using ILDasm or .NET Reflector.

Open Visual Studio command prompt... Run ILDasm

If you open the Manifest, you should be able to get the .ver, and mscorlib's version should be target version. For ex. the following DLL is using 4.0

// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely get it from [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). (See the screenshot below - the last thing listed is the Target Runtime.)

[image]

Comment: Oops. I see someone else suggested this. I'm voting that person up because they answered first, but I'll leave my answer for the screenshot, because I'm hoping it will save time and be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Load ILDASM and import your DLL. Double click on the 'Manifest' and it will display the framework version.

Answer (score 0):

I found *[How to identify the framework version a DLL is using](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/net-framework/26246-how-identify-framework-version-dll-using.html)*. It might mean writing a small secondary program to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

If using a utility is OK, I would recommend [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from [SysInternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals).